# Adding kotlin-bom to gradle dependency breaks the application

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, maven-bom, spotless

I am trying to update the build.gradle.kts by moving kotlin-bom from dependencyManagement to dependencies.
Am using java 17 and gradle 8.2

earlier it was

```
dependencyManagement {
imports {
   mavenBom("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.22")
} }
```

I am trying to move to dependencies

```
dependencies {

implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.22"))
}
```

I am doing this to add refresh version feature to my application.
But this is thowing the below error

> ```
>     Task :kaptGenerateStubsKotlin FAILED e: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void kotlin.script.experimental.api.KotlinType.<init>(kotlin.reflect.KClass, boolean, int, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker)'
>     at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.definitions.ScriptCompilationConfigurationFromDefinition$1.invoke(ScriptCompilationConfigurationFromDefinition.kt:32)
>     at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.definitions.ScriptCompilationConfigurationFromDefinition$1.invoke(ScriptCompilationConfigurationFromDefinition.kt:28)
>     at kotlin.script.experimental.api.ScriptCompilationConfiguration.<init>(scriptCompilation.kt:23)
>      at kotlin.script.experimental.api.ScriptCompilationConfiguration.<init>(scriptCompilation.kt:25)
>     at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.definitions.ScriptCompilationConfigurationFromDefinition.<init>(ScriptCompilationConfigurationFromDefinition.kt:27)
>     at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.definitions.ScriptDefinition$Companion.getDefault(ScriptDefinition.kt:221)
>     at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.ScriptingCompilerConfigurationExtensionKt.configureScriptDefinitions(ScriptingCompilerConfigurationExtension.kt:101)
>     at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.ScriptingCompilerConfigurationExtension.updateConfiguration(ScriptingCompilerConfigurationExtension.kt:50)
>     at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.configureProjectEnvironment(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:584)
>    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:192)
>    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:107)
>    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:442)
>    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:202)
>    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:153)
>    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
>    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:100)
>    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:46)
>    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
> ```

> Task :spotlessKotlin FAILED

> Step 'ktlint' found problem in 'src/main/kotlin/com/xxxxxx.kt':
> RANGE_UNTIL java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: RANGE_UNTIL

> ```
>    at com.pinterest.ktlint.rule.engine.core.api.ElementType.<clinit>(ElementType.kt:216)
>    at com.pinterest.ktlint.ruleset.standard.rules.AnnotationRule.<clinit>(AnnotationRule.kt:440)
>    at com.pinterest.ktlint.ruleset.standard.StandardRuleSetProvider$getRuleProviders$1.invoke(StandardRuleSetProvider.kt:88)
>     at com.pinterest.ktlint.ruleset.standard.StandardRuleSetProvider$getRuleProviders$1.invoke(StandardRuleSetProvider.kt:88)
>     at com.pinterest.ktlint.rule.engine.core.api.RuleProvider$Companion.invoke(RuleProvider.kt:43)
>     at com.pinterest.ktlint.ruleset.standard.StandardRuleSetProvider.getRuleProviders(StandardRuleSetProvider.kt:88)
>     at com.diffplug.spotless.glue.ktlint.compat.KtLintCompat0Dot49Dot0Adapter.format(KtLintCompat0Dot49Dot0Adapter.java:132)
>     at com.diffplug.spotless.glue.ktlint.KtlintFormatterFunc.applyWithFile(KtlintFormatterFunc.java:64)
>     at com.diffplug.spotless.FormatterFunc$NeedsFile.apply(FormatterFunc.java:154)
>     at com.diffplug.spotless.FormatterStepImpl$Standard.format(FormatterStepImpl.java:82)
>     at com.diffplug.spotless.FormatterStep$Strict.format(FormatterStep.java:88)
>     at com.diffplug.spotless.Formatter.compute(Formatter.java:246)
> ```

If I am using the first method, there are no errors.

If anyone knows what am doing wrong, please let me know. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Range Util was added to Kotlin in `1.9`.

Without more details it's unclear exactly what is going on, but it appears likely that previously somehow your application was using Kotlin 1.9 and now is using 1.8.

Try changing the version used in the platform to `1.9.0`

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/range-until.html